# Weird exception in WCF server

Tags: .net, wcf

Strange exception occurred, when I tried to call the action in my proxy class
exception message: The message could not be processed because the action 'http://testservice//reports/IReportService//Report' is invalid or unrecognized.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a typo that you have a second set of double forward slashes after 'testservice'?

'http://testservice//reports/IReportService/Report'

Comment: Yes, it's a typo and that's the problem, or just a typo in your question? If it is in the question only, please edit